# React-Native-Contacts: Cannot read property 'getAll' of null

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-development, react-native-contacts

I am following [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-contacts-how-to-access-a-devices-contact-list/) blog to set up react-native-contacts. After following the steps when I try to get all contacts

```
    Contacts.getAll().then((contacts) => {
      console.log(contacts)
    })
```

I get this error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of null`

For some reason importing *Contacts* from *react-native-contacts* appears to be null?

I am not sure if there is an issue with my set up. I followed up by reading over [react-natives-contacts](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts) set up instructions.

- Set up the correct permissions for android and iOS (currently testing on iOS simulator)

  - Android:

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
  {
    'title': 'Contacts',
    'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
    'buttonPositive': 'Please accept bare mortal'
  }
)
  .then(Contacts.getAll()
    .then((contacts) => {
        // work with contacts
          console.log(contacts)
        })
          .catch((e) => {
              console.log(e)
          }))

-----------------------------

// in AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

- iOS:

  - Added "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" key to info.plist

I am using RN 0.69 so auto linking should be enabled? not sure what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty new to react-native/mobile development so this may be obvious or not but I figured out the problem.

1. I am using **VS Code** and simply adding the key and string  to the info.plist file is **NOT** what you want to do. I was manually adding

```
<key>Privacy - Contacts Usage Description</key>
<string>insert message about accessing contacts...</string>
```

What you **WANT** to do is open up Xcode and add the key and string from the drop down selecting *Privacy - Contacts Usage Description* and adding the string within *info.plist*

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>insert message about accessing contacts...</string>
```

2. I run metro to run the bundle and test on the simulator. Should have rebuilt the package within Xcode or the command line running `$ npx react-native start run-ios` . Probably a noob mistake but there is my solution. Successfully accessing contacts now